# Normalizing the mantissa in floating point representation

Tags: binary-arithmetic, floating-point, rounding

How to represent $0.148 * 2^{14}$ in normalized floating point arithmetic with the format

```
1 - Sign bit
7 - Exponent in Excess-64 form
8 - Mantissa
```

$(0.148)_{10} = (0.00100101\;111...)_2$

We shift it 3 bits to left to make it normalized $(1.00101\;111)_2 * 2^{11}$.

Exponent = $11+64 = (75)_{10} = (1001011)_2$ and Mantissa = $(01001\;111)_2$.

So floating point representation is $(0\;1001011\;00101111)_2 = (4B2F)_{16}$ **Representation A**

But if we store the denormalized mantissa into 8 bit register, then it won't have stored the last three $1$s and then the mantissa would have normalized from $(0.00100101)_2$ to $(1.00101\;000)_2$ by inserting 3 $0$s instead of $1$s.

The representation would have been $(0\;1001011\;00101000)_2 = (4B28)_{16}$ **Representation B**

So while normalizing, does the processor takes into account the denormalized mantissa bits beyond 8 bits too? Or just rounds it off? Which one is correct: **A** or **B**?

Does it store the mantissa in fixed point representation? How does it all work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct binary representation of $0.145$ is $0.00100101000111...$

Normalized: $1.00101000111...$

The 8 bit mantissa is $00101000 = 0\mbox{x}28$

Comment: I made a mistake while calculating the binary representation. But how it would have worked if the binary number would be as I showed?

Comment: @Shashwat: 0x29 (remember that constants are usually converted to floating point representation at compile time or using *routines* like scanf() or parseFloat() so the processor is "unaware" of the representation of the number before the conversion )

Comment: The answer to the new question is Representation A (compiler (or scanf) does the dirty work and converts your number to its *closest* floating point normalized representation rounding it if necessary)