# Calculating sums of floating point numbers by hand

Tags: floating-point

how do you calculate the sum of 2.6125 * 10^1 and 4.150390625 * 10-1
by hand, assuming A and B are stored in the 16-bit half precision.
i cant figure out how to do this by hand with out losing most of the precision or getting it just plain wrong any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you start by representing this in binary scientific notation and showing sign, exponent and mantissa? To add exponents must be the same - have you tried it? There will be not normalized exponent - do you know what it means? Then you shift radix point of mantissa - can you do it and adjust exponent? Then you add mantissas, add signs, normalize and you have result. In meanwhile there might be truncation needed. One of the numbers you gave seem to be bigger than half precission...

Comment: Have you tried [reading this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7828/normalizing-the-mantissa-in-floating-point-representation)?